# No adapter attached; skipping layout recyclerview

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

the images are not displaying. in a SO example said to check the count in the adapter, but i think its correct.
I am getting this error in the logcat

```
No adapter attached; skipping layout recyclerview
```

this is the code mainactivity

```
RecyclerOkHttpHandler handler = new RecyclerOkHttpHandler( this, new RecyclerOkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(result,Search.this);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

this is my adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Listitem> mDataset;
    Context mContext;
    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //ImageView mImage;
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public ImageView image;
        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            txtHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            txtFooter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
             image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
    }


    public void add(int position, Listitem item) { //changed from string to listitem

        mDataset.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(String item) {
        int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Listitem> myDataset, Context context) {

        mDataset = myDataset;
        mContext = context;

    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {

            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ImageViewHolder vh = new ImageViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }


    private static final int TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_GROUP = 2;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // here your custom logic to choose the view type
        return position;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder TextViewHolder, int position) {

                ImageViewHolder viewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) TextViewHolder;
                //  viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(...)
        final Listitem item;

      //  final String name = mDataset.get(position);
        item = mDataset.get(position);
      //  viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getUrl());


        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(viewHolder.image);

              /*  viewHolder.txtFooter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        remove(item);
                    }
                });*/

               // viewHolder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));

        }


    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30581896/4224337)

Comment: It's not a fatal error, much more like a warning.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG well it didnt entered the okhttp class

Comment: @Rami ok i will check thanks

Comment: What is the use of calling mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  here?

Comment: @Rami I check the answer .. I didnt find difference between my code and the answer. I tried it

Comment: @Rami this shouldnt set it to recycler? 
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false))..  and what how to set it then ? and as for step 3 I have removed it

Comment: @KrupalShah I have removed it

Comment: @Moudiz Try to debug the code and check if it enter to *myMethod()* method

Comment: @Rami you are the man !, you were right it didnt access the myMethod because I forget to the `execute` the okhttp needs execute to work. please added as answer to accept, thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your code and check if `myMethod()` method is executed.

Also there is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you create the adapter.

```
public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
       mAdapter = new MyAdapter(result,Search.this);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I should add execute okhttp to access my interface

Answer (score 1):

Please  remove  **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** before setting the Adapter in following lines of code. You can do it once adapter is set for RecyclerView.

```
  @Override
        public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(result,Search.this);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I did what you said , and still got the error  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Ok tell me // viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));  commented code in Adapter working? I mean is text is displaying correctly?As error No adapter attached; skipping layout recyclerview is ok as you are not setting adapter in onCreate() of activity of onCreateView() of fragment, you doing in background thread. So this warning is seems fine to me.

Comment: thanks for your support my mistake was I didnt add execute for okhhtp. , when I added it worked. thanks for your support

Comment: Oh..silly mistakes.. :P , sometimes happens . You are welcome.